# How to order by column name when getting a list of columns their data types using DESCRIBE in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need a way to figure out how to get the list of columns in alphabetical order when using the DESCRIBE command in SQL Developer. Something like desc table order by Name; this won't work of course but something along these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the way the result of a DESCRIBE command are displayed, but you could query the system catalog directly:

```
select column_name, data_type, column_id
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
order by column_name
```

If the current user does not own the table you are looking at, use `all_tab_columns` but you have to provide the owner name as well:

```
select column_name, data_type, column_id
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
  and owner = 'SOME_USER'
order by column_name
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this. It gives an empty table as the output.

Comment: @pikachu: then you provided the wrong table name for the condition `where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'`

Comment: It's not working. I think it's a schema issue. I did select * from user_tab_columns and found just one table. It might have a different syntax when you are accessing tables from the "other users" folder in the database server.

Comment: `user_tab_columns` only shows columns from tables **owned** (=created) by the current user. If you want to see columns from tables owned by other users, use `all_tab_columns`

Answer (score 5):

a_horse_with_no_name and Littlefoot are BOTH right, but where does that leave you?

If you'd like, you can create a new command that will get you what you want.

In [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html) -

```
SQL> alias alphadesc=select column_name, data_type, column_id
  2  from user_tab_columns 
  3  where table_name = upper(:tablename)
  4* order by column_name;
```

We can take advantage of the ALIAS command, used to basically create shortcuts for predefined bits of SQL or PL/SQL.

[image]

you're in sql developer - you could do this there as well, either using the ALIAS feature (would need to go into your login default script for connections, or you could create a code template)

PS SQLcl is our modern take on SQLPlus, it's available as a small standalone, but it's also in your SQL Developer / bin directory

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to query `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.

In its simplest way, that would be

```
select *
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE_NAME'
order by column_name;
```